# Add value tag to a html Element

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, htmlelements

[Picture In Response to a Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruwK9.jpg)
[What The Webpage looks Like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFhdv.jpg)

```
<input name="ftitle" class="inputbox ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" autocomplete="off">
```

I need to add value=  to the above HTML input element
How do I go about doing this? For the life of me, I can Not Figure it out.

Edit: I need this because I need to fill in a text box that is on a web page that does not contain the value= in it. But if I right click on it and add attribute value= then I can change the text through my program.

I am using C# web browser control so I'm using

```
HtmlElement NewAttribute = doc.GetElementById("ftitle");
```

So when everything is said and done it will look like this.

```
<input name="ftitle" class="inputbox ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" 
 autocomplete="off" value="">
```

Here what I got so far if it helps to see what I am up to. this is all for a different web page but I am doing the same thing but I need to add the class "value"

```
 private void Generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {




        HtmlDocument doc = wbNewProject.Document;



        HtmlElement wbJobName = doc.GetElementById("Name"); //lblcontact.text
        HtmlElement wbEngineer = doc.GetElementById("engineer-lookup"); //
        HtmlElement wbSalesEng = doc.GetElementById("SalesEngineerUserId");
        HtmlElement wbLocation = doc.GetElementById("Location");
        HtmlElement wbBidDate = doc.GetElementById("BidDate");
        HtmlElement wbPriorApproval = doc.GetElementById("PriorApproval"); //True or False
        HtmlElement wbTakeOff = doc.GetElementById("TakeOffComplete"); //True or False
        HtmlElement wbProject = doc.GetElementById("RoleType"); //Design/Build or Plan/Spec
        HtmlElement element = wbNewProject.Document.GetElementById("ftitle");




        try
        {
            wbJobName.SetAttribute("value", lblJobName.Text);

            if (lblContact.Text.Contains("Dan"))
                wbSalesEng.SetAttribute("value", "2");
            if (lblContact.Text.Contains("Kelley"))
                wbSalesEng.SetAttribute("value", "3");
            if (lblContact.Text.Contains("Erv"))
                wbSalesEng.SetAttribute("value", "4");
            if (lblContact.Text.Contains("Marc"))
                wbSalesEng.SetAttribute("value", "5");
            if (lblContact.Text.Contains("Terry"))
                wbSalesEng.SetAttribute("value", "6");
            if (lblContact.Text.Contains("Chad"))
                wbSalesEng.SetAttribute("value", "7");
            if (lblContact.Text.Contains("Jacob Lenertz"))
                wbSalesEng.SetAttribute("value", "10");
            if (lblContact.Text.Contains("Terry"))
                wbSalesEng.SetAttribute("value", "11");
            if (lblContact.Text.Contains("Nate"))
                wbSalesEng.SetAttribute("value", "12");

            wbLocation.SetAttribute("value", lblLocation.Text);
            wbBidDate.SetAttribute("value", lblBidDate.Text);

            if (lblPriorApp.Text.Contains("Yes"))
                wbPriorApproval.SetAttribute("value", "true");
            if (lblPriorApp.Text.Contains("No"))
                wbPriorApproval.SetAttribute("value", "false");
            if (lblTakeOff.Text.Contains("Done"))
                wbTakeOff.SetAttribute("value", "true");
            if (lblTakeOff.Text.Contains("Not Done"))
                wbTakeOff.SetAttribute("value", "false");

            wbEngineer.SetAttribute("value", lblEngineer.Text);
            wbProject.SetAttribute("value", lblProject.Text);
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need a `value` tag, it is defined as a `text` which jQuery can access via `$('[name="title"]').val();` and when you do a form post via MVC, if the parameter `ftitle` is used, it would pass when the form is submitted.

Comment: i added a edit to explain

Comment: Can you tell me the namespace of the HtmlElement class? Is it  System.Windows.Forms?

Comment: Yes The clase is System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Javascript

```
document.getElementById(elementName).value = "your value";
```

### jQuery

```
$('#elementName').val() = "your value";
```

Both approaches will require you to create an **Id** on your element. However, jQuery will also allow you to select your element by [other means other than an Id](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

### Web forms c#

This is also simple, use the [SetAttribute Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.setattribute(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
HtmlElement element = doc.GetElementById("ftitle"); //Your have this, correct?

element.SetAttribute("value", "your value");
```

Comment: i am using C# with web browser control

Comment: yes getting close the problem im having when im using .SetAttribute one there is no "value" to be found i need to create that "value". If that makes sense

Comment: @JacobLenertz updated my answer, check if it works for you.

Comment: this gives me an error that is underlines saying "Operator '==' cannot be applied to the operands of type 'strimg' and 'bool' Also i cant find the Attributes.Add any where

Comment: According to the documentation of SetAttribute, it should define a new attribute even if the attribute didn't exist before: *If attributeName is not a defined attribute on an element, M:System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement.SetAttribute(System.String,System.String) will define it on the element as a new attribute.*

Comment: So then i have to be doing somethign else wrong because the "ftitle" is the name= part and that can be used as the id according to examples i have seen.

Comment: Breakpoint your code just before the SetAttribute method and see if the element was found, and if it was found, if it is the correct one.

Comment: Yeah so i am an idiot the way i have it set up is i have my main form then my alt form thats in a panel and i have the text boxes coming over from the main form on my New Job button click but not on the New button that summons the form... Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

You could do this incredible hokey approach:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var title = @model.Title;
     $('[name="title"]').val(title);
});
```

You can also implement Razor directly:

```
<input type="text" value="@model.Title" />
```

Keep in mind though, if @model is null, you'll receive an application error.  But as denoted it is an approach.  The approach I would honestly take, would be a JavaScript template, then parse my data model directly to the template, then append the template directly into the View State.

Comment: i cant do that in C#

Comment: @JacobLenertz Well, what framework are you using?  You can't get proper answers, without proper outline.

Comment: im using 4.0 or VS 2017 just the normal web browser control